# How to read documents from Change Feed in Azure Cosmos DB since last checkpoint after restart?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am using Change Feed processor library to read the Change Feed on a partitioned collection and below is the code for how I have configure it. I ma using most of the default options.

```
ChangeFeedProcessorOptions feedProcessorOptions = new 
{          
   LeaseRenewInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
};

var docObserverFactory = DocumentFeedObserverFactory.Create(this.destinationCollectionInfo, this.dbRepository);
this.builder
    .WithHostName(hostName)
    .WithFeedCollection(this.monitoredCollectionInfo)
    .WithLeaseCollection(this.leaseCollectionInfo)
    .WithProcessorOptions(feedProcessorOptions)
    .WithObserverFactory(docObserverFactory);
```

This runs fine as long as the Change Feed application is running and documents are being inserted/updated in the collection and the Change Feed app picks them up as expected.

The problem happens when I stop the Change Feed app for sometime and insert/update few documents in the Collection. Then when I start the Change Feed app, it doesn't pick changes from where it last left. Those changes that were inserted when the Change Feed app was stopped are lost. But when I set the flag StartFromBeginning to true, it picks everything from the start including changes that were inserted when the Change Feed app was stopped in between for sometime.

My understanding of read from current (StartFromBeginning to false) is that the Change Feed reads documents since it last left. But that doesn't seem to happen. Please help.

Comment: The CFP Library checkpoints automatically when the code in `ProcessChangesAsync` completes. Normal troubleshooting is: 1. Check the leases `ContinuationToken` value when you stop the App. 2. Do your inserts 3. If the `ContinuationToken` value changed, then you have another CFP library processing that same collection with the same lease collection (you can use LeasePrefix in this case). 4. If value did not change (check if its null), restart the App, it should pick up the changes (if the value was not null)

Comment: I don't have multiple CFP libraries processing the feed. The behavior you mentioned is happening only if I set **_StartFromBeginning_** to true in **_ChangeFeedProcessorOptions_**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to continue from exactly where you left it.

The first, and more accurate one, is to store the Continuation token of the last thing you read. That way you can specify it when you start again and it will win over both the `StartTime` and the `StartFromBeginning` flags.

The second one is to provide the `StartTime` property which will try and find the continuation token of a given time automatically. It has an approximate 5 second precision so there is a chance that you might miss some documents though.

Comment: I ran below two tests with StartFromBeginning flag set to true using the Change Feed processor library.  

**1.** Lease collection is empty. Insert documents in the monitored collection. Start Change Feed app. All changes received from the first document as expected.  
**2.** Stop Change Feed app. Insert more documents. Start Change Feed app. Received only the newly inserted documents. That is, it is reading from where it last left. This is what I need.  
**3.** Stop Change Feed app. Delete all documents from Lease Collection. Start Change Feed. Receives all documents from  start.

Comment: The behavior in 2 is what I need but not sure if I can rely on the StartFromBeginning and if it will always be consistent. From the documentation, StartFromBeginning should read from beginning but in case of restarts, it is reading from where it last left.

Comment: StartFromBeginning will only work if there are no leases or leases have ContinuationToken null. Otherwise, CFP will always start from the last checkpointed ContinuationToken.